# system("pause") has "stopped" working

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have been using the command `system("pause")` in Visual C++ 2008 and Visual C++ 2012 for many years. But recently when I was trying to use that command, it stopped working in both compilers. The recent activity that I did was installing Java with all the components.

What is the reason for this?  What can be done about this?

Comment: Define "it does worked [sic]".

Comment: the pausing  of the command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use system("pause"): http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html

Try cin.get() to get a keystroke.

Comment: That is true.But what is the reason for this?